# Association Tables

Tags: database-theory

I can use an association (or ‘linking’) table to model a many-to-many relationship, eg `Student` <- `Enrolment` ->`Course`, where an enrolment describes an essential relationship between students and courses.

I can also have `Course` -> `Department` and `Course` -> `Language`, where language and department are both attributes of a course, but there’s no special relationship between them.

These two scenarios look similar, but I wouldn’t call `Course` an association table... is there another name for it? Is there a logical way to distinguish between the two cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technical name for your `association (or 'linking') table` is an [`associative entity`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) - there are ~ 15 alternative names listed on that page. I explore the logic behind these [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/188997/34007) - in particular that the `PRIMARY KEY` for a linking table should be the combination of both `FOREIGN KEY`s in the linking table.

Without seeing your DDL, it strikes me that your `Course -> Department` and `Course -> Language` tables are examples of your common or garden `Parent -> Child` relationship. These are explained clearly and simply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7881015/470530).

The parent table field must either be the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table or at the very least `UNIQUE` (and indexed in that case, `PK`s normally being indexed automatically). The child table field obviously doesn't have to be `UNIQUE` but **should** be indexed because it would normally be the `JOIN`ing field in any SQL queries. Thanks to the delights of `NULL` value logic, a `UNIQUE` parent field **can** be `NULL` (see fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7b43bf4abd215ecef7df9d848231e8f5)), however I would **strongly** recommend adding a `NOT NULL` constraint to that parent field!

I would imagine that your `Course -> Department` scenario would look something like this (see the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e2ca2bb707cf4139f13c70dd7220cdef) - example is PostgreSQL but it works for every server on dbfiddle.uk):

```
CREATE TABLE department
(
  dept_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  dept_name VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
  dept_head INTEGER,  -- this could relate to an id in a personnel table, allowed to be NULL if position is vacant
  dept_contact INTEGER, -- id of secretary to the head of department?
  dept_address VARCHAR (100),
  --
  -- other fields
  --
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE course
(
  course_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  course_code VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
  course_name VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
  course_dept INTEGER NOT NULL,
  --
  --  other fields
  --
  CONSTRAINT course_dept_fk FOREIGN KEY (course_dept) REFERENCES department (dept_id)
);
```

The important part (for this discussion) of these table declarations is:

```
CONSTRAINT course_dept_fk FOREIGN KEY (course_dept) REFERENCES department (dept_id)
```

So, the `department` table in this case is the parent and the child table is `course` which I imagine is the thrust of your question. The `CONSTRAINT` means that for any `course_dept` entry in the `course` table, there **must** be a corresponding entry in the `department` table!  If you find this explanation unsatisfactory, please let me know (why) and I'll try to clarify further.

p.s. welcome to the forum!