# Having clause question maybe

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables.

1. Grades
2. Disciplines
3. Students

I want to select only the disciplines that doesn't have grade 2. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT DISTINCT DISC_NAME
FROM STUDENTS, DISCIPLINES, GRADES
WHERE 
GRADES.ID= STUDENTS.ID
AND
GRADES.KOD_DISC = DISCIPLINES.DISC_ID
GROUP BY GRADE
HAVING
GRADE != 2
```

Comment: Please check  [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: Create a db<>fiddle or similar with enough sample data to demonstrate the problem. There is an easy solution to your problem, the hazzle is to figure out what your tables look like

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! A schema [like this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=f5446478b78f86ad166b7f41442047e8) might be of help - adapted from [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/188997/34007). It's always good to provide a fiddle - as @Lennart suggested. Also important, (and it's especially so for MySQL - lots of new features recently!), is to provide your server version either as a tag or prominently in the text of your question.

Comment: Vérace, seems like this is the right method, great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HAVING` is for filtering on aggregated results. You could use it to solve your problem if you rewrite it slightly so it's filtering on the number of times a `DISC_NAME` has a result from your joins which has `GRADE=1`. For this aggregate, you'd be grouping by the `DISC_NAME` and you can count matches with a `case when`

```
select d.disc_name
from students s
    ,disciplines d
    ,grades g
where g.id= s.id
and   g.kod_disc = d.disc_id
group by d.disc_name
having sum(case when g.grade = 2 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

(assuming the `grade` column comes from `grades` and `disc_name` is part of `disciplines`)

You could also achieve the same with an anti-join query. Here I've removed the join to `students` because you don't seem to use it (other than making sure the `grade` row belongs to a `student` row, which I would assume isn't necessary). I've also switched to using more modern ansi join syntax - you could use either.

```
select d.disc_name
from disciplines d
where not exists (select null
                  from   grades g
                  where  d.disc_id = g.disc_id
                  and    g.grade = 2
                 )
```

Comment: I explained it bad and not detailed enough, but your querry worked nice.