# Is there a benefit to using a surrogate key for a many-to-many table?

Tags: sql-server, performance, index

It is understood that a table with a clustered index with non-sequential value(s) will cause fragmentation due to page splitting.

In my case, I'm working with a pair of `uniqueidentifier`s in a many-to-many table and that is the context for this question.

**Consider the following tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Car](
    [CarID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
    ...
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Option](
    [OptionID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
    ...
)

-- This is the table that will be queried
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Car_Option](
    [CarID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [OptionID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [LastEdit] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
```

I've have read the suggestion to use some sort of surrogate key when using non-sequential identifiers (for example, adding an `ID INT` field to `[Car_Option]`) to prevent page splitting, however I don't think this applies here and that is what I'm looking to confirm.

If the main lookup value `CarID` is not part of `Car_Option`'s clustered index, I'll need an additional non-clustered index to cover that `CarID` column which, I believe, will become just as fragmented as if it were the clustered index because we'd still be inserting non-sequential values. **Is this a correct statement?**

#### Option 1

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Car_Option](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,      -- Clustered Index
    [CarID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,    -- Non-Clustered Index
    [OptionID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL, -- Non-Clustered Index
    [LastEdit] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
```

#### Option 2

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Car_Option](
    [CarID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,    -- Clustered Index
    [OptionID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL, -- Clustered Index
    [LastEdit] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
```

I'm inclined to do Option 2 and put a clustered index on `(CarID, OptionID)`.

**Question: Is there any advantage to using a surrogate key in Option 1 if we never lookup from it and are only querying from, say, the CarID?**

*Note: I am aware that index maintenance would be required if using Option 2 non-sequential values*

**Update 1:** It is a requirement to use a `Uniqueidentifier` for `CarID` and `OptionID`. The system is very mature and it would take immense effort to change that. The designs of the `Car` and `Option` table are not really anything that can reasonibly be changed at this point, the focus is strictly on how using a surrogate key will or will not help my specific query scenario which will look something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Car_Option 
INNER JOIN Option ON Option.OptionID = Car_Option.OptionID
WHERE CarID IN (
   '80297476-f104-406e-bf2c-535042f2db4e',
   'a6486941-57af-42f4-ae72-ef939581e209', 
   'etc...'
)
```

Comment: Please clear few doubt .Why are you using uniqueidentifier in first place.Is it business requirement ?Do you want to show to end user ? Is it for Security purpose ?

Comment: @KumarHarsh, I've updated the question.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head.  A key on (CarID,OptionID) is required.  An index on (OptionID) is also required.  Adding a _third_ surrogate key is just wasteful.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, I'm thinking an index on OptionID would not be required necessarily unless I was also looking up from OptionID. This *may* happen but it would be very few and far between.

Comment: It's required if you lookup by OptionID, or if you delete Options at runtime.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/188995/are-composite-primary-keys-bad-practice/188997#188997)!

Answer (score 2):

Let me rephrase your questions

> 1 Should I use ID column for cross reference table

IMHO if you don't plan to reference to this table you don't need ID and compound primary key (CarID, OptionID) is possible.

> 2 What should I use as clustered index

I think on this stage of the game fragmentation should not be in your focus until you get feedback from users proving it is the problem. You should focus on logical design of your tables - define primary keys and foreign key constraints
Next step will be choose that index should be the clustered one.

You are correct that page splits are inevitable anyways (for clustered or non clustered indexes)

I think your choice of clustered primary key of (CarID, OptionID) is a good start.
However don't forget about index on OptionID for Car_Option

Answer (score -1):

Main reason to use `uniqueidentifiers`

i) Since GUID are more or less unique,they are helpful in multiple database scenario
where databases will be merge,i.e. primary key wont clash

ii) Also GUID are hard to remember so they are ok from business point of view

Main Disadvantage

i) `GUID` (16 bytes ) are 4 times heavier than `INT` (4 bytes ).So index build on `GUID` will be larger and slower than index build on `INT` columns.

Page splitting

Say in table `[dbo].[Car]` and `[dbo].[Option]` there are 10 columns or more than 10 columns some of which are varchar.Also it may contain millions of records. In this case there will be high page fragmentation's insert and Select both will suffer from performance.

In case of `[dbo].[Car_Option]` page fragmentation will be less because its contain only 3 columns. Still it will have more data page as compared to `INT` column as clustered Index.

> If the lookup value CarID is not part of Car_Option's clustered index,
> I'll need an additional non-clustered index to cover that CarID column
> which, I believe, will become just as fragmented as if it were the
> clustered index because we'd still be inserting non-sequential values.

Sql optimizer build multiple plan and compare the cost of each and choose the plan which cost less.Sql optimizer often choose good enough plan
Size of Clustered index is more than Non clustered Index .In case of GUID as Clustered Index size of clustered will be more than Non Clustered index.

In short,Since CI is Wider than NCI, Sql optimizer may choose Non Clustered index plan even of there is one more step involved.

Even though `uniqueidentifiers` is requirement. I will add `INT` surrogate key  in all 3 tables.Let `INT` surrogate key interact with each other.
Also perform testing in Test or Staging server with real data and analyze the execution plan of important query and check their performance.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Car](
    CID int identity(1,1) primary key
    [CarID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
    ...
)

CarID is NonClsutered Index here

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Option](
     OID int identity(1,1) primary key
    [OptionID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
    ...
)

OptionID is NonClsutered Index here

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Car_Option](
    CID int,
    OID int,
    [LastEdit] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
Create ClusteredIndex CI_Car_Option on [Car_Option](cid,oid)

create table #temp (cid int)
insert into #temp(cid)
Select cid from Car 
WHERE CarID IN (
   '80297476-f104-406e-bf2c-535042f2db4e',
   'a6486941-57af-42f4-ae72-ef939581e209', 
   'etc...'
)

SELECT Option.* ,
FROM Car_Option CO
INNER JOIN Option ON Option.OID = Car_Option.OID
inner join #temp t on t.cid=CO.cid
```

Also it is important to add Trusted Forieng Key constrain in
`[dbo].[Car_Option]`

There may be few more line of query, but performance is main goal. Without and Test data I am not sure, but in other real example it has work well.

Its all about testing few option in Test/Staging server then deciding.
Main objective is to look for overall performance. Even if you have to wrote few line for query.

> Question: Is there any advantage to using a surrogate key here if we
> never lookup from it?

Already answer above.

Other option is to Add `Trusted Foreign Key` constraint in `CarOption` table.
Sql optimizer uses Trusted Foreign key in making execution plan. It enhance the performance of Select query.

But  BULK Insert/Update performance suffer, If there is no bulk insert then you can ignore the performance. OR you can disable the Trusted FK before bulk insert and enable after bulk insert is over.

**Note** : It is assume that these table will contain million of record and there will be frequent insert/update and Select

Comment: Thank you - there is good information within this answer, however most of it doesn't really have to do with my actual question. I've updated my question to hopefully provide some better guidance to get a more specific answer about the use of a surrogate key if we're never actually performing lookups using that key. And then secondarily, I'm looking to confirm my understanding of how a non-clustered index on CarID, OptionID would become just as fragmented as a clustered index on those same two columns in the situation where we also had a surrogate clustered index.